# what does an item without namespace mean in style

Tags: android, namespaces

```
<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/bg_action_bar</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_action_bar</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_red</item>
</style>

<style name="My_Style" parent="style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_action_back</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_action_back</item>
</style>
```

What is the difference between 'homeAsUpIndicator' and 'android:homeAsUpIndicator' or 'background' and 'android:background' ?

I wonder if I need to set them both? I just found these examples, but could not find what you are setting when you don't use the 'android' namespace...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Due to limitations in Android's theming system any theme
>   customizations must be declared in two attributes. **The normal
>   android-prefixed attributes apply the theme to the native action bar
>   and the unprefixed attributes are for the custom implementation.** Since
>   both theming APIs are exactly the same you need only reference your
>   customizations twice rather than having to implement them twice.

*The easiest way to convey exactly what this entails is with an example. The following is the full theme from the “Styled” example mentioned above:*

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Read more about [ActionbarSherlock's Mirrored Attributes](http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html)

Comment: OMG sorry, I see I should have read the page of ActionBarSherlock instead trying to google on this. Thanks!